# Multi-line command execution over remote SSH

Tags: ssh, sh

I want to execute multiple lines of shell commands over remote ssh.

According to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1459/remote-for-loop-over-ssh, I just need to use single quotes to execute a multi-line for loop. Here is what I tried:

`` ssh user@server ‘cd ~/Data; cwd=pwd; for i in `find 201806 -name "day_*"`; do echo $i; cd $i; a.sh; cd $cwd; done’ ``

Since nothing happens, I am speculating that there is a syntax error that I must not be understanding. 201806 is the name of a folder in the Data directory, and I have tested that the command works without the `ssh user@server`. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: `‘` and `’` are the wrong apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ssh -v user@server ‘cd ~/Data; cwd=`pwd`; for i in `find 201806 -name "day_*"`; do echo $i; cd $i; ./a.sh; cd $cwd; done’
```

Also, make sure your **a.sh** file have execute permission. **-v** option will give debugging messages about its progress.